# Deck trimming lumber option

Tags: deck, trim, decking

I am building a deck with 2x8 joists so the trim would be around 2x10 to have a look like these:

[image]

OR

[image]

However, I am not sure which materials to choose.

**Option 1**

This one is pressure treated but it is more appropriate to be for framing, right? I mean if I paint it white, would it look good considering how thick and rough it is? What is another wood alternative for nice looking white board?

http://www.lowes.com/pd_476182-10926-476182___?productId=50017316&pl=1&Ntt=2x10+deck

**Option 2**

I was looking at PVC but those are very expensive. And I am not sure if they are good for decking?

http://www.homedepot.com/p/Veranda-3-4-in-x-9-1-4-in-x-8-ft-White-PVC-Trim-3-Pack-IN5416445/203640258

**Option 3**

Going with the Trex white since I use Trex

http://www.lowes.com/ProductDisplay?partNumber=343649-63201-940127

However, I don't know if this is overkill or not?!

What are other options of material?

Comment: What "look" are you after, exactly - the picture (as seen by the shadows) is of a 2x3 or 2x4 lower rail that is well above the decking, not anything 2x10-ish. If you are using plastic deck wood, I'd strongly suggest sticking to that - painted wood bits on decks are a maintenance hassle that plastic deck boards save you from.

Comment: I am looking for a seamless board that is white from the outside. I modified with a new picture. This deck is from my friend's house and the white board is just painted wood. How "bad" could this painted wood get over the years in term of maintenance. He said it looks the same for the last 6 years. I am using Trex Select for the deck. This could be my board http://www.lowes.com/ProductDisplay?partNumber=343649-63201-940127 but I am wondering if it's overkilled.